# Advertisement for boating holidays

Tags: time, reading-comprehension

> Sail through England!
> Narrowboat Holiday UK offers canal boats for
> hire for family boating holidays. Envision weekend and midweek breaks
> on the canals and waterways of the Yorkshire Dales, sail through the
> scenic countryside, passing villages and castles. Our luxurious range
> of rental boats are ideally equipped for your canal boating holiday.
> Each boat is equipped with central heating, hot water, toilets, and
> self-catering. We give a full training session before you start.
>
> - Weekend Breaks 
>    Depart Friday afternoon around 2.00 pm and return the boat to the boatyard by 10.00 am on Monday morning.
> - Midweek Breaks 
>   2.00 pm Monday afternoon to Friday morning at 10.00 am. Same price as for the Weekend Break.

Could anyone rephrase for me the two sections 'Weekend Breaks' and 'Midweek Breaks', please? The question I have to answer is:

> When does the customer have to return the boat if he or she leaves on Monday?
>
> (A) Next Monday morning
>  (B) Friday 10:00 am
>  (C) Friday 2:00 pm
>  (D) Saturday 10:00 pm

I used Google Translate, but it didn't help. Any help would be appreciated.

I don't understand the context of the advertisement, and then I'm confused with words like 'leave' or 'break'.

Comment: It says: 'Midweek Breaks: 2.00 pm Monday afternoon to **Friday** morning at **10.00 am**'. Please say what you don't understand about that.

Comment: _Break_ here means a short holiday. _Leaves on Monday_ means 'takes the boat away from the boatyard on Monday' (at the start of the holiday).

Comment: I would use: Weekend Getaways, and not breaks! The original is pretty clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Leave" means the same as "depart", and a "break" is a word for a short holiday.  So there is this information:

| Type | Leave | Return |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Weekend | Friday 2pm | Monday 10am |
| Midweek | Monday 2pm | Friday 10am |

If you leave on Monday, what type is it?

If you leave Monday, when do you return?

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me a lot.

Comment: Can you explain how it helped?  I don't think I've answered the question at all.  I've just put the same words from your question in a table...

Comment: It's just that I don't understand the context of the advertisement, and then I'm confused with words like 'leave' or 'break'. I interpreted them the wrong way.

Comment: You should add that information to the question.

Comment: Oh, noted. Again, thank you very much